# How can I link to a specific moderator flag for discussion with other mods?

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderation, permalink

For discussion purposes I'd like to link to a specific moderator flag (for instance, in chat, or over IM or some other medium). I can't see anything in the UI indicating that this is possible. If it's not possible, could it be made possible? If it is, could someone tell me how (and consider making it clearer so I can find it)?

Answer (score 2):

Let's not clutter up the flags with back and forth comments.

Make use of the chat and create a private room where you can invite the other moderators of the site.

Don't link to the flag, link to the post and leave a message as to what is wrong with the post or user.

You'll be afforded much more line space to hack it out and discuss the finer points of how long you'll be suspending the user that's caught your eye.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant - I want to link to a flag in chat, not have comments within the moderator flag environment.

Comment: @Rahul Perhaps you could add to your post why linking to the flagged post isn't suitable.

Comment: there is no way to even link to a "handled flag", I guess you can link to the post but you can never get the body of the old flag

Comment: Have people forgotten how to quote?